# Maui EventToCommandBehavior how to pass multiple parameters

Tags: c#, xaml, parameters, maui, collectionview

### What I'm trying to accomplish

I have an `EventToCommandBehavior` command that passes an event argument as a parameter to the command: the "CheckedChanged" event argument.  I need to it pass a normal old parameter, too.

[image]

It's probably just a matter of syntax, and I haven't found the right doc.  I hope so.

### My current code

Pretty simple stuff, really.  The command takes place in a `Chcekbox` control in a `CollectionView`.  Basically, I have a list of type "Video" (a class of my own) displayed, with a checkbox next to each one.  When the user clicks on the checkbox I go to a method.  I need to pass two arguments:

(1) the `CheckChangedEventArg`, which I pass, and
(2) the object that we're looking at, "Video", which I can't figure out how to pass along with the `CheckChangedEventArg`.

Here's the XAML:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="VideoList">
  ...
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Video">
        ...
               <CheckBox>
                   <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                       <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                            x:TypeArguments="CheckedChangedEventArgs"
                            EventName="CheckedChanged"
                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=BindingContext.AddRemoveFromListCommand}"/>
                  </CheckBox.Behaviors>
              </CheckBox>
       ...
   </DataTemplate>
  ...
</CollectionView>
```

Here's the ViewModel:

```
[RelayCommand]
public void AddRemoveFromList(CheckedChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Value)
    {
          // do the thing
    }
    else
    {
          // do the other thing
    }
}
```

Note that this is *working code*, only it only passes `CheckedChangedEVentArgs`.  I need it to pass both `CheckedChangedEventArgs` and the `Video` (mentioned in the `<DataTemplate/>` attribute).

### What have I tried?

I tried [reading the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior).  The answer may be in there, but I can't find it.  The name of the attribute `xTypeArguments` is plural, leading me to think that maybe I could simply add another argument?

And, alas, I have access to the `Video` object in that attribute!
[image]

This leads me to think that maybe all I need to do is this:

```
<CheckBox.Behaviors>
    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            x:TypeArguments="CheckedChangedEventArgs, Video (model)"
            EventName="CheckedChanged"
            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=BindingContext.AddRemoveFromListCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding VideoFilename}"
            />
</CheckBox.Behaviors>
```

And:

```
    [RelayCommand]
    public void AddRemoveFromList(CheckedChangedEventArgs args, Video video)
    {
            ...
    }
```

But that doesn't work.

I did a ton of other stuff, too, involving `CommandParameter`, but nothing worked.

Does anyone know what to do here?

### Solution Update

Stephen Quan's suggestion worked.  Thank you Mr. Quan.  Here's the solution:

To rehash, my entire goal is this:  when the user selects one of the objects in the `CollectionView` it gets added to an `ObservableCollection` list and passed on to another part of the app.

[image]

Here's the solution:

- add a Boolean property to the `Video` object.  Let's call it `VideoIsChecked`.
- In the `CollectionView`, when the checkbox is selected, Bind `VideoIsChecked` to the native Checkbox property `IsChecked`.
- From here I can simply loop through the list of `Video` objects.  If that `Video` object's `VideoIsChecked` property is true, add it to a list of "User Selected Videos".

Here's the new `Checkbox` Xaml.  I entirely removed the method that fired when the checkbox was selected is entirely removed as it's no longer needed, and the property `Video.VideoIsChecked` is bound to the `IsChecked` Checkbox property.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox"
          ScaleX="1.5"
          ScaleY="1.5"
          Color="#000063"
          HorizontalOptions="End"
          IsChecked="{Binding VideoIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

In the `ViewModel` I go as far as declaring the property:

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool videoIsChecked;
```

And I declare the property in the model `Video`:

```
namespace Project.Model;
public class Video
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool VideoIsChecked { get; set; }
      ...
}
```

Finally, when the user has selected their videos and hit a button that says something like "Finished", I create a list of the selected Videos and send it to the next page. Here's the part where I go through the Videos and see which ones have `VideoIsChecked is true`:

```
private async Task CreateListOfSelectedVideos()
{
   foreach (Video video in Videos)
   {
      if (video.VideoIsChecked)
      {
         SelectedVideos.Add(video);
      }
   }

   ...

}
```

That's it!  Nice, simple solution!

Comment: I don't think you can with `EventToCommandBehavior`.  Possible you could write your own custom behavior to do it, but it would be a LOT easier to just use the `CheckedChanged` event in the code-behind, which could then call your VM method.  Or you might be able to use the `SelectedItem` property, if it is getting set when you click the checkbox

Comment: Have you thought about doing `IsChecked="{Binding VideoIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"` ? That way, your `Video` view model will receive change notification via the VideoIsChecked setter and, because the signal is being raised in the view model you know which one is being added/deleted. Using LINQ or a `.Where` on your collection, you can quickly assemble a list of checked videos anytime.

Comment: @Jason So you're saying that I can create a normal, non-MvvM code behind method that uses the `CheckedChanged` event, and from inside that method call a method in my ViewModel?  I will try.

Comment: @Jason, I can write an event handler that fires when the checkbox is checked.  I can even call a method to my ViewModel from the code-behind event handler.  What I can't do is pass parameters from Xaml >> Code Behind >> ViewModel (which is the essence of my problem).  I need to be able to pass the object that I'm looking at in the `CollectionView`  (or even one of the strings that I'm using in a Label -- the name of the object).  This seems like robbing Peter to pay Paul.

Comment: why can't you pass a parameter to a VM method?

Comment: `var control = (Checkbox)sender;` to get the control in the event handler.  Then `var item = (MyClass)control.BindingContext;` to get the bound object

Comment: @Jason Hmmm... I will try that.  I will also stop being scared about Code-Behind.  Thank you.  As it turns out, Stephen Quan's suggestion above worked.  I don't need to fire a method at all, just change a Boolean value in the object that I'm working with if the `CheckedChanged` changes and simply add all of the objects with that bools as "true" to a list when I leave.  Easy-peasy.  With that said, I will still attempt to pass a param to the code behind, because the pattern of "XAML >> CodeBehind >> ViewModel" sounds like it could be SUPER useful.

Comment: @StephenQuan your suggestion worked!  Easy-peasy!  I'll update my question to reflect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass `CheckedChangedEventArgs` and `Video (model)` at the same time. We can pass the video Item(including the checked value of the CheckBox) as a whole.

You can just add a bool variable(e.g. `public bool VideoIsChecked`) to your Video model and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your Video Item(Suppose the Videl Model is `Video.cs`), then bind it to the property `VideoIsChecked` of this `CheckBox`. Of course, if you use nuget [MVVM Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm-community-toolkit-features),you can simply this code.

Once we check or uncheck the `CheckBox`, the value of this variable will be updated. So, we can pass the whole Video Item.

You can refer to the following code. Here, I inherited the `ObservableObject` for the Video model not `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

**Video.cs**

```
public partial class Video:ObservableObject
{
    //I add a property to identify the name of the video
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool videoIsChecked;
}
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

Here, we can get the whole video item by following code:

```
public ICommand AddRemoveFromListCommand { get; set; }

AddRemoveFromListCommand = new Command<Video>(DoSomething);

private void DoSomething(Video item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item.VideoIsChecked)
            {
                // you also need to add some other logic codes here
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Title}");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Title}");

            }
        }
    }
```

You can refer to the whole code of MyViewModel:

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Video> VideoList { get; set; }

    //define the AddRemoveFromListCommand for the CheckBox
    public ICommand AddRemoveFromListCommand { get; set; }


    public ObservableCollection<Video> SelectedVideos { get; set; }
    // you can  get all the selected Videos based on the value of property videoIsChecked
    public ICommand GetSelectedVideosCommand { get; set; }


    public MyViewModel() {
        VideoList = new ObservableCollection<Video>();// initialize the VideoList
        VideoList.Add(new Video { Title="video1", VideoIsChecked = true});
        VideoList.Add(new Video { Title="video2", VideoIsChecked = false});
        VideoList.Add(new Video { Title="video3", VideoIsChecked = false});

        SelectedVideos = new ObservableCollection<Video>(); // initialize the SelectedVideos

        AddRemoveFromListCommand = new Command<Video>(DoSomething);

        GetSelectedVideosCommand= new Command(GetAllSelectedVideos);

    }

    private void GetAllSelectedVideos()
    {
        foreach (Video video in VideoList)
        {
            if (video.VideoIsChecked)
            {
                // add the video to the selectedlist
                SelectedVideos.Add(video);
            }
        }

    }

    private void DoSomething(Video item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item.VideoIsChecked)
            {
                // you also need to add some other logic codes here
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Title}");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Title}");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

3.Usage example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiVideoListApp.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MauiVideoListApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:MyViewModel></viewmodels:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding VideoList}" x:Name="myCollectionView">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <CheckBox Color="#0B4C90" IsChecked="{Binding VideoIsChecked}">
                            <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                                    Command="{Binding BindingContext.AddRemoveFromListCommand, Source={x:Reference myCollectionView}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                    EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                            </CheckBox.Behaviors>

                        </CheckBox>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                       FontSize="20"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       TextColor="#0B4C90"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <Button Text="Get Result" Command="{Binding GetSelectedVideosCommand}"  />
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

I also added a Button to get all the selected video list.

```
    // you can  get all the selected Videos based on the value of property videoIsChecked
    public ICommand GetSelectedVideosCommand { get; set; }

    GetSelectedVideosCommand= new Command(GetAllSelectedVideos);

   private void GetAllSelectedVideos()
    {
        foreach (Video video in VideoList)
        {
            if (video.VideoIsChecked)
            {
                // add the video to the selectedlist
                SelectedVideos.Add(video);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Jessie, there's a lot here that's over my head.  What is it that's over my head, you ask?  Alas, I'm still at that stage of ignorance of "not knowing what I don't know".  Here's one that's off the top of my head:  in your ViewModel example, you inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  I'm already inheriting `ObservableObject` in my ViewModel, so I don't see how that's possible.  With all that said, I will give this a shot.  
.

Comment: Yes, if you have already inherited `ObservableObject `, you don't need to inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged` while the former is a simplification of the latter. In fact, your implementation is similar to mine, but the code is different.

Comment: I  have updated my answer,and replaced `INotifyPropertyChanged ` with `ObservableObject`. You can check it.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I'm going to ignore the `EventToCommandBehavior` portion of your question, but, I am going to focus on your core requirements:

- 1. reacting to CheckBox changes in your Video view model,
- 2. maintaining a list of selected videos

The first part can be done via `IsChecked="{Binding VideoIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"` so that your Video view model will receive notifications via the `VideoIsChecked` setter. The second part can be done by LINQ or a `.Where()` call on your list with a `VideoIsChecked` filter.

Here's the Video view model (N.B. because, from your comments, I derived that you are using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm, so, I'm going to make use of CommunityToolkit.Mvvm features here):

```cs
// Video.cs ...

public partial class Video : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _id;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _videoIsChecked = false;

    // ...
}
```

`ObservableObject` has a `PropertyChanged` event handler which we will use for bubbling up changes from your Video view model to your parent view model.

For simplicity, I made `MainPage` act as the parent view model. It has both `VideoList` and `SelectedVideos` collections. The `SelectedVideos` property is implemented with a getter function that dynamically evaluates the selected video collection but we only trigger reevaluation if we see `PropertyChanged` events coming from any of the `Videos` in our `VideoList` collection:

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs ...

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public List<Video> VideoList { get; } = new List<Video>()
    {
        new Video() { Id=1, VideoIsChecked = false },
        new Video() { Id=2, VideoIsChecked = false },
        new Video() { Id=3, VideoIsChecked = false },
    };

    public List<Video> SelectedVideos => VideoList.Where(v => v.VideoIsChecked).ToList();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        for (int i = 0; i < VideoList.Count; i++)
            VideoList[i].PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Video.VideoIsChecked))
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedVideos));
            };
    }
}
```

Here's a minimal XAML showing both the parent `VideoList` with the `CheckBox` and the subsequent bindings to the `SelectedVideos` collection:

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding VideoList}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Video">
                <HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Id, StringFormat='Video Id: {0}'}" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding VideoIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"  VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

    <Label Text="{Binding SelectedVideos.Count, StringFormat='Selected Videos: {0}'} "/>

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedVideos}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Video">
                <Label Text="{Binding Id, StringFormat='Selected Video Id: {0}'}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

A working example can be found here: https://github.com/stephenquan/StackOverflow.Maui/tree/main/StackOverflow.Maui.Mvvm.CheckBox

[image: CheckBoxMVVM.gif]

Comment: Stephen, I owe you a check mark, but I can't check both you and the gentleman below.  Both of you put in considerable work teaching me this stuff, and I truly appreciate it.  I'm going to read through your answers elsewhere and when I find something that teaches me something I'll check it.  That's sort of cheating, but I'll be legit.

Comment: @Bob no worries.